# Symfony 5 - Last accessed page matches "fos_js_routing_js"

Tags: symfony, twig, fosjsroutingbundle

I have the following problem where I've added the [FosJSRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html) to my project, and added the links  to my base template

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

I can generate a couple of routes which I use for AJAX calls. But the problem occurs after a succesful login, which instead of matching to the [last accessed page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#redirecting-to-the-last-accessed-page-with-targetpathtrait), is matching the route "fos_js_routing_js", and then shows a white page with the following content:

```
/**/fos.Router.setData({"base_url":"","routes":{"..."}});
```

My firewall has a pretty basic setup

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: users
        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            name: remember_me
            always_remember_me: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
```

And I've tried several solutions like [adding/editing new pattern to the firewall](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/140#issuecomment-105236357) but with no success.

The [LoginAuthenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#generating-the-login-form) is the same one as the one generated from the `make:auth` command. The part concerning the redirecting is the method `onAuthenticationSuccess`:

```
/**
 * @param Request        $request
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 * @param string         $providerKey
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey): RedirectResponse
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey))
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
    throw new Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside ' . __FILE__);
}
```

When I dump the `$request->getSession()` part on login, I see the it's redirecting to `js/routing`:

```
[
  "_security.main.target_path" => "https://mydomain.local/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"
  "_csrf/https-ajax" => "..."
  "_csrf/https-authenticate" => "..."
  "_security.last_username" => "YTZ"
]
```

Isn't the pattern in dev supposed to stop this from happening in the first place or do I misunderstand its usage?

**EDIT**

I've mentioned the link to the "last accessed page" for the `RequestSubscriber` earlier, and I've added `'/js/routing' === $request->getPathInfo()` to the if statement in the `onKernelRequest` method:

```
if (
     !$event->isMasterRequest()
     || $request->isXmlHttpRequest()
     || 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
     || '/js/routing' === $request->getPathInfo()
)
{
   return;
}
```

The above works, but it seems more like a workaround than an actual solution.

Comment: Your firewall config looks good. Can you show the LoginAuthenticator?

Comment: @dbrumann Sorry for the late response. I've added the information to the question. It's the same authentication as in the documentation, created by the `make:auth` command. I've also dumped the response to show that it goes to `js/routing` instead of the real last accessed pages.